# Visual Basic Function with nested Subroutines or Functions

Tags: vb.net, function

I'm pretty new to Visual Basic, and I'm having a little trouble trying to create a class that is responsible for ensuring the web service proxies session is still valid. In order to do this there are several methods that need to be called so I'm trying to figure out how I can nest all of those methods into a single function that will then return the proxy object back before proceeding to another method. Here's a pseudo example of what I'm trying to do

```
Public Shared Function CheckSession(ByVal cookie As String) As ServiceProxy

'first check if cookie is still valid calling one service method
Sub CheckCookie()
Dim ap As AuthenticationProxy = New AuthenticationProxy
AddHandler ap.CheckCookieCompleted, AddressOf CheckCookieCallback
ap.CheckCookieAsync(cookie)
End Sub
Sub CheckCookieCallback(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e As CheckCookieCompletedEventArgs)
Dim result as Boolean = e.Results.status

'from here based on session status I will either finish the function or move on to another method for getting a new cookie from the server

'at the end of the function I will have the proxy class used by other methods
End Function
```

So then what I would want to do is when I actually want to use the ServiceProxy I would first call this function, so like this below (the cookie string is stored in IsolatedStorage but for simplicity of this I'm not including all of that and just a quick example):

```
Public Sub VerifyCredentials(ByVal name as String, ByVal pass as String)
Dim proxy as ServiceProxy = CheckSession(cookie)
'''...
```

Comment: This looks like vb.net.

Comment: why cant `CheckSession` just call a self contained `CheckCookie` sub (redone as a function)?

Comment: @Plutonix I would still need to nest some functions and/or sub's if the session isn't valid. Basically it works like this, the Cookie is checked against the server, if it's still valid then the cookie is added to the web service proxy and the method can be called. If it's not valid then first a UUID is issued from one service method and then that UUID is passed to the next method to get the new Cookie. I'm just not sure on how to wrap all of those methods into a function that will kick back a valid cookie for every other method in the web service.